# Записать данные в массив (memcache | PHP)

Tags: массивы, кэширование, php

Всех приветствую. Есть одна небольшая проблема с `memcache`.

Суть в том, что кэшируется массив $result, после чего, если он закэширован, берется значение и записывается в массив $result снова. Как можно достать $value по первому ключу? Например, link_download?

```
$var_key = $memcache->get($_POST['link']);
if(!empty($var_key)) {
    foreach($var_key as $value) {
        $result['link_download'] = $value['link_download']; // Не работает
        $result['discription'] = $value; // Работает
    }
}
else {
    foreach($html->find('.class') as $value) {
        $result['link_download'] = pq($value)->find('a:eq(1)')->attr('href');
        $result['discription'] = pq($value)->find('tr:eq(0) > td:eq(1)')->html(); 
    }
}

if(empty($var_key)) {
    $memcache->replace($_POST['link'], $result); 
    $memcache->set($_POST['link'], $result, false, 1*60);
}
```

**var_dump**: array(2) { ["link_download"]=> string(34) "link here"; ["discription"]=> string(3712)" (то есть, просто передается ключ, как быть?)

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, разобрался. Туплю, как обычно. Естественно, не нужен foreach.

```
$result['link_download'] = $var_key['link_download'];
$result['discription'] = $var_key['discription'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. вы серьёзно полагаете что это может заработать?

```
if(empty($var_key)) {
foreach($var_key as $value) {
```

Давайте попробуем прочитать: 
Если переменная $var_key пустая, то перебираем её как массив в foreach.

Перебираем пустоту. По вашему это возможно?

Comment: @dimka3210, извиняюсь, это просто опечатка, т.к код писал прямо в textarea. Сейчас исправлю. Пожалуйста, посмотрите внимательно var_dump, и, возможно, вы скажите мне, как быть в данной ситуации?